# Is there a way to create an index on a set of words (not all words) in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I want to have some sort of limited indexed Full-text search. With FTS postgres will index all the words in the text, but I want it to track only a given set of words. For example, I have a database of tweets, and I want them to be indexed by special words that I give: awesome, terrible and etc.

Comment: You might want to look into creating a custom dictionary for postgres: https://postgresql.verite.pro/blog/2019/03/28/tsearch-dictionary.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone will be interested in such a specific thing, I made it by creating a custom dictionary (thanks Mark).

My findings I documented here: https://hackmd.io/@z889TbyuRlm0vFIqFl_AYQ/r1gKJQBZS